# linked list or array , how to solve this que?

Tags: arrays, recursion, linked-list

We define a matched ordered pair as the following:

Given, some integer K, (a, b) is a matched ordered pair if and only if a + b = K and a ≤ b.

We are given an array of N integers. Some arrays are GOOD while others are BAD.

The objective of the
problem is to check whether the given array is GOOD or not.

We define a GOOD array recursively:
An empty array is GOOD.
Consider a 2-sized array [a, b]. This array is GOOD if and only if (a, b) is a matched ordered pair.

Note
that: This array is not GOOD even if (b, a) is matched ordered pair. For example, if K = 10, the array
[2, 8] is GOOD while the array [7, 3] is not GOOD.
The subarray enclosed within a matched ordered pair is GOOD. Note that: A matched ordered pair
in an array must be of the form (ai
, aj ) where i < j and ai is the integer at index i.

The following are some examples of GOOD arrays for K = 10:

```
[1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9], [1, 9, 3, 7], [1, 5, 5, 9, 3, 2, 8, 7]
```

The following are some examples of BAD arrays for K = 10:

```
[1, 2, 9, 8], [9, 2, 8, 1]
```

I am not able to solve this pratise question. how should i approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What comes in, must come out. We could write this, `[1, 5, 5, 9, 3, 2, 8, 7]` as

```
[1, 5, 5, 9, 3, 2, 8, 7]
 (  (  )  )  (  (  )  )
```

Use the same logic for checking for valid parentheses.

Python code:

```py
def f(arr, k):
  stack = [arr[0]]

  for i in xrange(1, len(arr)):
    if stack:
      last = stack[ len(stack) - 1 ]
      if arr[i] >= last and arr[i] + last == k:
        print str(last) + ' ' + str(arr[i]) + ' match! Popping...'
        stack.pop()
        continue      
    stack.append(arr[i])

  return 'GOOD' if not stack else 'BAD'
```

Output:

```py
=> f([1, 5, 5, 9, 3, 2, 8, 7], 10)
5 5 match! Popping...
1 9 match! Popping...
2 8 match! Popping...
3 7 match! Popping...
=> 'GOOD'

=> f([9, 2, 8, 1], 10)
2 8 match! Popping...
=> 'BAD'
```

Answer (score 0):

1.take first element, ( a)
2.compare with all other elements(b) to check if its sum gives K(=10)
3.if sum gives K(=10),
      i)check if a<=b is true, then remove a and b from the array and repeat from step1.
      ii)if a<=b is false, then its BAD array. No further steps needed 
4. If sum doesn’t give K(=10),
    Then its BAD array. No further steps needed